# PHP postrgres SQL executing a query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

i'm having problems in executing a query inside php. I have the following query in my php code:

```
    $nome = pg_escape_string($_POST['cnome']);

$obtem_idb = "SELECT idb FROM banda WHERE nome = $nome";

echo("$nome");

$idb = pg_query($connection, $obtem_idb);
if(!$idb){
        die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
    } else { 
echo("o idb que vem da query é $idb");
}
```

The name i print is correct, but when trying to execute the query i get the following error:

```
Error in SQL query: ERROR: column "anthrax" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT idb FROM banda WHERE nome = Anthrax ^
```

Can anyone help, i can't seem to find the error.

When i put the variable $nome in single quotes the value of it changes to 'Resource id #2' and i get the following error:

```
Error in SQL query: ERROR: insert or update on table "edicao" violates foreign key constraint "edicao_idb_fkey" DETAIL: Key (idb)=(Resource id #2) is not present in table "banda".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten quotes around the value:

```
$obtem_idb = "SELECT idb FROM banda WHERE nome = '$nome'";
                                                 ^-----^--- must be quoted
```

Comment: When i put nome in single quotes i get the following error:  Resource id #2Error in SQL query: ERROR: insert or update on table "edicao" violates foreign key constraint "edicao_idb_fkey" DETAIL: Key (idb)=(Resource id #2) is not present in table "banda".

Comment: that's a whole other query causing that error. a select query can NOT produce a foreign key violation.

Comment: When i execute the query, the result that comes from it is "Resource id #2" and "B-7" as it should...

Comment: That's because a query() call returns a result HANDLE, not the data you've requested from the DB. You still have to actually FETCH a row of data and extract the value you want before you can insert that value into another query.

Answer (score 1):

you need to quote $nome in your sql query

```
$obtem_idb = "SELECT idb FROM banda WHERE nome = '$nome'";
```

Comment: When i put nome in single quotes i get the following error:  Resource id #2Error in SQL query: ERROR: insert or update on table "edicao" violates foreign key constraint "edicao_idb_fkey" DETAIL: Key (idb)=(Resource id #2) is not present in table "banda".

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your $nome reference in single quotes:

```
$obtem_idb = "SELECT idb FROM banda WHERE nome = '$nome'";
```

Comment: When i put nome in single quotes i get the following error:  Resource id #2Error in SQL query: ERROR: insert or update on table "edicao" violates foreign key constraint "edicao_idb_fkey" DETAIL: Key (idb)=(Resource id #2) is not present in table "banda".